# grabbing audio from sound card in linux

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, audio-streaming, alsa, pulseaudio

i am new baby to linux environment.so plz help me, I want to redirect audio stream into file which currently playing on speaker. but they must not be mix to each other if there two or more media player are running at same time. every stream which coming from one  particular application must be dump the raw data into one particular file. i am using ubuntu 12.04 which have alsa and pulseaudio. so plz which API should i use ?....& how to do it????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i got  the  solution , I am using pulse audio API for my project . for more information go to http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/